# How does app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints() affect the endpoint matching process in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm slowly getting to know ASP.NET Core Routing [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#routing-basics).
It says: Apps typically don't need to call UseRouting or UseEndpoints. WebApplicationBuilder configures a middleware pipeline that wraps middleware added in Program.cs with UseRouting and UseEndpoints. However, apps can change the order in which UseRouting and UseEndpoints run by calling these methods explicitly.

As far as I can see the next code should return "Inspect Endpoint." in "/" route, and "Out of available endpoints" everywhere else. Instead, I always get "Out of available endpoints" as a response.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Inspect Endpoint.");

app.Run(async context =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Out of available endpoints");
});

app.Run();
```

But if I add the next statements before the `app.MapGet(...)`, the result turns out to be as expected:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(_ => { });
```

Can you explain why is that and what am I getting wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core, the order of middleware registration matters. The `UseRouting()` and `UseEndpoints()` methods configure routing middleware, which is essential for routing requests to the appropriate endpoint handlers.

In your initial code snippet, you haven't explicitly configured routing middleware using `UseRouting()` and `UseEndpoints()`. Therefore, the request processing pipeline doesn't include routing logic, and all requests are handled by the default terminal middleware added with `app.Run()`.

When you add `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseEndpoints()` before `app.MapGet(...)`, you're explicitly configuring routing middleware, allowing the application to route requests to the defined endpoint handlers correctly. Consequently, your / route handler becomes active, and you receive the expected response.